# 'Add to Contacts' hyperlink in Pages (iOS/iCloud)

Tags: ios, contacts, pages, iwork

I'm a one-day novice at Pages (iOS/iCloud). I just figured out how include hyperlinks for emailing (`mailto:xxx@xxx.xxx`) and calling (`tel:+00000`), but as of yet I couldn't work out how to include a hyperlink in a Pages document that adds a Contact (plus details) or something equivalent (vcard?) (or a similar action like giving the option to add the contact). Can you help out?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could only upload the vCard somewhere and link to it from your document (note: only iOS 7 supports opening vCards that way afaik)